# Proper way to write this php conditional statement

Tags: php, wordpress

I am not well versed in php as I'm a newbie in it. I'm trying to use these lines of code but getting error. What is the proper way to write this:

```
<?php 
if ( function_exists( 'wpsabox_author_box' ) ) {
    echo wpsabox_author_box();
} else {
    echo (
            '<div class="postauthor">
                <div class="authorprofilepix">'
                     get_avatar( get_the_author_id() , 80 );
                '</div>

                <div class="authorprofile">
                    <h4>' the_author(); '</h4>
                    <p>' the_author_description(); '</p>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>

            </div><!--end postauthor-->');

}
?>
```

Thanks in anticipation!

Comment: WHat error are you getting?

Comment: You need the dot `.` to concatenate strings.

Comment: @VinodVT as i said on the comment to your now deleted answer, thats simply not true

Comment: Ok I will remove that comment

Answer (score 3):

You should add dots between the strings and function calls inside the echo call.

e.g.

```
echo ('string' . function() . ' string ');
```

Comment: drop the semicolon

Answer (score 1):

use this way :

```
<?php if (function_exists( 'wpsabox_author_box' ) ) {
            echo wpsabox_author_box();
        } else { ?>
         <div class="postauthor">
            <div class="authorprofilepix">'
             <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_id() , 80 ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="authorprofile">
                <h4><?php echo  the_author(); ?></h4>
                <p><?php echo the_author_description(); ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>

        </div><!--end postauthor-->

   <?php     }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how your code should look in order to work:

```
<?php 
if ( function_exists( 'wpsabox_author_box' ) ) {
    echo wpsabox_author_box();
} else {
    echo '<div class="postauthor">
            <div class="authorprofilepix">' . get_avatar(get_the_author_id(), 80 ); . '</div>
                <div class="authorprofile">
                    <h4>' . the_author() . '</h4>
                    <p>' . the_author_description() . '</p>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>

            </div><!--end postauthor-->';    
}
?>
```

Here's the prefered solution:

```
<?php if (function_exists( 'wpsabox_author_box' ) ) {
            echo wpsabox_author_box();
        } else { ?>
         <div class="postauthor">
            <div class="authorprofilepix">
             <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_id() , 80 ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="authorprofile">
                <h4><?php the_author(); ?></h4>
                <p><?php the_author_description(); ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>

        </div><!--end postauthor-->

   <?php     }

 ?>
```

As you can see it's slightly correctd Ravi's solution. I can't say it's better but I much prefer it to the other cause it's much more clear.

One more thing. Don't use `the_author_description()` function, use `the_author_meta('description')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use commas to avoid string concatenation. Also, use get_the_author_meta() as both the get_the_author_id() and the_author_description() have been deprecated.

```
if ( function_exists( 'wpsabox_author_box' ) ) {
    echo wpsabox_author_box();
} else {
    echo  '<div class="postauthor">
            <div class="authorprofilepix">',
                 get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('ID') , 80 ),
            '</div>

            <div class="authorprofile">
                <h4>', get_the_author(), '</h4>
                <p>', get_the_author_meta('description'), '</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>

        </div><!--end postauthor-->';
}
```